# Dataframe with items as str array, convert to multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some input data, which has a structure such that items can be a single entry, but also a str that is actually an array, but was not yet converted. A basic example would look like this:

```
d = {
    'col1': ['[5.02, 1, 3, 2]', '[2.002, 3.14, 4.5, 6.000153, 3]'],
    'col2': ['[1.01, 1.02, 2, 4, 5, 10]', '[2, 3.05, 4.001, 7]'],
    'col3': [5.2, 3]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
                              col1                       col2  col3
0                  [5.02, 1, 3, 2]  [1.01, 1.02, 2, 4, 5, 10]   5.2
1  [2.002, 3.14, 4.5, 6.000153, 3]        [2, 3.05, 4.001, 7]   3.0
```

Each row corresponds to a dataset, each column represents one type of measurement within that dataset and the entries in each item correspond to the actual measurement data.
Currently, the strings are converted to numpy arrays, but each item in col1 and col2 will still hold an array.
So a lot of the code that follows with make use apply to perform calculations on the datasets, which I suspect is highly inefficient (confirmation would be good here) as it takes quite some time. Should note that in the real data there are many more rows and columns, so efficiency is important.
Thus, I think it might make sense to handle this data differently and instead convert the data to a multiindex, where the first index selects the dataset (so the row in the above example) and the second index refers to the data point in each dataset.
It is however important to know that I can't rely on all of those datasets having the same length, I have to assume a variable length.

Since I have only very little experience with pandas multi index, can someone help me out here how to convert this data in an efficient way into a pandas multi index?
The result should look like this:

```
                     col1   col2   col3
dataset  data point
0        0           5.02   1.01   5.2
         1              1   1.02
         2              3      2
         3              2      4
         4                     5
         5                    10
1        0          2.002      2   3.0
         1           3.14   3.05
         2            4.5  4.001
         3       6.000153      7
         4              3
```

Any help / suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the data always a string representation of numbers as a list?

Comment: Initially yes. There is code to convert each entry to a numpy array. This is done via `.apply(lambda x: self.str_to_array(x))` in a loop over the corresponding columns. But this seems to be expensive as well, so maybe it would be good to replace that, too. Which is why I started with the original structure in the example.

Comment: I see, I provided two approaches then. One using a regex and a more generic one with `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try them out and report back asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option taking advantage of the fact that [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) adds a second level:

```
out = pd.concat({c: df[c].str.extractall('(\d+\.?\d*)')[0].astype(float)
                 if df[c].dtype == object else df[c].set_axis(
                       pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[c].index, [0]])
                    )
                 for c in df}, axis=1
               ).sort_index().rename_axis(['dataset', 'data point'])
```

Or:

```
out = pd.concat({c: df[c].astype(str)
                         .str.extractall('(\d+\.?\d*)')[0]
                         .astype(float)
                 for c in df}, axis=1
               ).sort_index().rename_axis(['dataset', 'data point'])
```

Or using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
from ast import literal_eval

def expand(s):
    if s.dtype == object:
        s = s.apply(literal_eval).explode()
    return s.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex
                        .from_arrays([s.index,
                                      s.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),
                                     ], names=['dataset', 'data point'])
                     )

out = pd.concat({c: expand(df[c]) for c in df}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                        col1   col2  col3
dataset data point                       
0       0               5.02   1.01   5.2
        1                  1   1.02   NaN
        2                  3      2   NaN
        3                  2      4   NaN
1       0              2.002      2   3.0
        1               3.14   3.05   NaN
        2                4.5  4.001   NaN
        3           6.000153      7   NaN
        4                  3    NaN   NaN
0       4                NaN      5   NaN
        5                NaN     10   NaN
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've had to tackle quite a few problems first before I could finally evaluate this.

So from these I do like the explode variant the most, so I'll be using that one, I think. However, while literal_eval is a good suggestion for general evaluation, in my case it's much too slow. So I'll replaced that with something else (based on string manupulation and np.array) targeting exactly the cases that I expect in my data, which is orders of magnitudes faster.

Regex is quick, it might be an option, but at least for the moment I'll use basic string manuplation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import zip_longest

# if necessary, convert string to lists
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(literal_eval)
df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(literal_eval)


out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        *df.apply(
            lambda x: [
                (i, *t)
                for i, t in enumerate(
                    zip_longest(
                        [x.name], x["col1"], x["col2"], [x["col3"]], fillvalue=""
                    )
                )
            ],
            axis=1,
        ).explode()
    ],
    columns=["datapoint", "dataset", "col1", "col2", "col3"],
).set_index(["dataset", "datapoint"])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                       col1   col2 col3
dataset datapoint                      
0       0              5.02   1.01  5.2
        1                 1   1.02     
        2                 3      2     
        3                 2      4     
        4                        5     
        5                       10     
1       0             2.002      2  3.0
        1              3.14   3.05     
        2               4.5  4.001     
        3          6.000153      7     
        4                 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I opted for the other solution, so I don't need to generate a list of columns to convert first. It's a good suggestion nonetheless. :)